# How to fix the isuue that he code block can`t work in hexo blog pages?

Tags: markdown, blogs, hexo

I have just used github pages + hexo to creat my hexo blog.However,when using code block,it didn`t work at all and I wonder how to fix it.
The code in md file is:

````
```js
var allp=$("div p");
allp.attr("class",function(i,n){
           return Number(n)+1;
      });
```      

```js
allp.each(function(){
        console.log(this);
        });
```
````

but in browser,what I saw is:

[image]

I have tried many ways to fix it but failed. Btw,I use the Next theme of hexo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you need is this

```html
{% codeblock code snippet 1 lang:js %}
var allp=$("div p");
allp.attr("class",function(i,n){
           return Number(n)+1;
      });
{% endcodeblock %}     

{% codeblock code snippet 2 lang:js %}
allp.each(function(){
        console.log(this);
        });
{% endcodeblock %}
```

Put the above code in your md file and you'll get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xh8W.png).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try these steps:
1. enable the highlight at theme's _config.yml, especially the 'auto_detect';

```
 highlight:
      enable: true
      auto_detect: true
      line_number: true
      tab_replace:
```

2. clean the cache by `hexo clean`;
3. restart the server by `hexo s`;